# Intercept double properties javascript function like document.getElementById

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript script  that has a lot of this function

```
document.getElementById(id)
```

an I don't want the script to stop on any undefined return from this function,So the solution is to intercept any call with a hook similar function , I use this code to do the interception:

```
var f = document.getElementById.bind(document);
    document.getElementById = function (id) {
        if(f(id) !== null) return true;
    return false;
}
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById('ajax').style.display = "block";
}
```

Now, this script is working great for the first degree chaining properties like this :

```
document.getElementById("html").innerHtml = "Hello"
```

or

```
document.getElementById("txt").disabled = true;
```

And the script will bypass the function and does not throw any error on false return, but when adding another propoerty like this one :

```
document.getElementById('ajax').style.display = "block";
```

then the script will throw a :

> TypeError: document.getElementById(...).style is undefined

if we have something to cause the script to die when finding that the result is null (No DOM element with that id) from the function hook , that will sole the issue, but I cannot find to do die or exit function other than return false.

Comment: `So the solution is to intercept any call with a hook similar function` I disagree here. However your problem is that you are not null-checking before you traverse an object tree. So sure, `document.getElementById` can't return null, but nothing says its subjobjects can't be null.

Comment: Your returning a bool, if it finds the element or not. If it does find the element you need to return that element, instead of true.

Answer (score 0):

Your replacement function returns either `true` or `false`. It never returns the original return value of the *real* `document.getElementById()`.

If you really want to make something like that work, you'll need to return an object that mocks many of the DOM APIs that code might expect from a real DOM node. Returning just `false` won't really make anything better.

Comment: @JohnTaa well a JavaScript mechanism that mocks arbitrary DOM nodes is not exactly simple. In my opinion, you'd be much better off fixing the code that fails when `getElementById()` returns `null`. Or, you could consider using a library like jQuery that handles that for you.